# VBA Copy/paste static ranges to static ranges in dynamically built array of worksheets

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to copy the cell values of 4 static ranges from one worksheet and paste those values into the cells within 4 static ranges for each worksheet that is included in my dynamically built list.

Here is my code:

```
Sub retpsh()
Dim Home As Worksheet: Set Home = Worksheets("Home")
Dim s3 As Worksheet: Set s3 = Worksheets("Sheet3")
Dim s9 As Worksheet: Set s9 = Worksheets("Sheet9")
Dim s5 As Worksheet: Set s5 = Worksheets("Sheet5")
Dim s7 As Worksheet: Set s7 = Worksheets("Sheet7")
Dim Back As Worksheet: Set Back = Worksheets("Home Backstage")
Dim wsarray As Variant
Dim message As String: message = Back.Cells(18, 13)
Dim ws As Variant

If Back.Cells(18, 19) = 0 Then
    If MsgBox("Nothing selected!", vbOKOnly) = vbOK Then Exit Sub
Else
    If MsgBox(message + " Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
    wsarray = Array(Back.Cells(18, 19)) 'Doesn't work properly
End If

For Each ws In wsarray
    ws.Range("C2:C5", "C8:C11", "C13", "B18:C22") = Worksheets("Home Backstage").Range("B1:B4", "B6:B9", "B11", "B18:C22").Value '''''450 error with or without "Set" before line
Next ws

End Sub
```

First, `wsarray = Array(Back.Cells(18, 19))` does not work as it is not parsing that cell value, it takes the whole thing as a single value (i.e. `"s3","s5","s7","s9"` or whatever the cell value is). `Back.Cells(18, 19)` has a formula that builds the list based on the 4 options selected on the "Home" page. The formula builds the list to be any of the 16 combinations of: s3, s5, s7, or s9. The final cell value looks like: `"s3"` or like `"s3","s7","s9"`. Using just `Dim wsarray()` or `wsarray() =` doesn't change the behavior. Any time I use `wsarray()` without `Array(...)` I get a `'13' Type mismatch` error.

1. Is this a matter of dynamically defining the dimensions of the array
   first?
2. If not, is there a way to parse the cell value into the array?
3. If not, how would I build the array list dynamically in VBA?

Second, even bypassing the above issues by specifying the array manually, I still get a `'450' Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment` error. I know setting one range with multiple nonconsecutive cells = another range setup the same way works fine (e.g. `Range("K15:C18","C29") = Range("C1:C4","C15")`), so:

4. Why is that syntax not working within the `For` loop?

Third, the statement within the `For` loop needs the fully qualified name `Worksheets("Home Backstage")` and did not accept the alias `Back`.

5. Why does the `For` not accept the worksheet alias `Back`?
6. Does the `For` loop act outside of the `Dim`'s that are setup prior to it thus needing the `Dim` within the loop?

I know I could get around all of this with a bunch of `If` statements and referencing the state of each of the 4 options on the "Home" page to determine which worksheets to copy to, but I don't like that idea. That doesn't seem to be the right way to go about this, having a bunch of duplicated code with slight changes to predicates hence my desire to use an array. Nevertheless, my questions are more "why" than "how", but I appreciate any guidance or explanations all the same!

Comment: first problem: `wsarray = Split(Back.Cells(18, 19),",")`  Second problem you will need to do each area separately, you can not assign a disjointed range value to a disjointed range.

Comment: @Scott, did you even read the whole post? I know `wsarray = Back.Cells(18, 19).Value` doesn't work, hence my first 3 questions. As for the second part of your comment, why is it that `Range("K15:C18","C29") = Range("C1:C4","C15")` works just fine if ran on its own, but does not within the `For` loop?

Comment: see the edit, use split.  Also with the second part you cannot use a string to equate to vba variable names.  You will need to do something different to loop through the sheets.

Comment: @ScottCraner, I didn't use split as I thought it was a string data type and would conflict with the `For` loop's need for a Variant data type, but never bothered to test it. I'm happy to report that after removing the quotes from the names, it parses correctly! Thanks!

Comment: The cell value is a string, but your array is a variant, thus once the string is split to an array each element will take the array's type assuming it can be converted to that target type. Variant though is an oddball and isn't really a type itself. It can take anything except for fixed length strings, which I've never actually seen anyone use in VBA.

Comment: and as to the disconnected range, no it does not work: `Range("K15:C18","C29")` is not a disconnected range.  Put `? Range("K15:C18","C29").Address` in the immediate window and you will get `$C$15:$K$29` not `$K$15:$C$18,$C$29`  and even after fixing the errors `ws.Range("C2:C5,C8:C11,C13,B18:C22").Value = Back.Range("B1:B4,B6:B9,B11,B18:C22").Value` does not do anything.

Comment: @JNevill, Ah, the good ol' implicit conversion! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @ScottCraner, You are correct. I was thinking it did work correctly, but as you pointed out "K15:C18","C29" does get evaluated to "C15:K29". It just happened to be that I had white space in all other cells during my test which made it look like it was working as desired. Time to change that up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to enter the actual sheet names in the cell:

```
sheet9,sheet7
```

equating a string or variable with a variable name does not work, so you will need to loop through the array created by Split and make sure the sheet exists, then use it.

You cannot use range with more than two cell references.  Range expects a start and a finish.

```
Sub retpsh()
Dim Home As Worksheet: Set Home = Worksheets("Home")
Dim Back As Worksheet: Set Back = Worksheets("Home Backstage")
Dim wsarray() As String
Dim message As String: message = Back.Cells(18, 13)
Dim i As Long
    If Back.Cells(18, 19) = 0 Then
        If MsgBox("Nothing selected!", vbOKOnly) = vbOK Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If MsgBox(message + " Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        wsarray = Split(Back.Cells(18, 19).Value, ",")
    End If

    For i = LBound(wsarray) To UBound(wsarray)
        If Not IsError(Application.Evaluate("'" & wsarray(i) & "'!A1")) Then
            With Worksheets(wsarray(i))
                .Range("C2:C5").Value = Back.Range("B1:B4").Value
                .Range("C8:C11").Value = Back.Range("B6:B9").Value
                .Range("C13").Value = Back.Range("B11").Value
                .Range("B18:C22").Value = Back.Range("B18:C22").Value
            End With
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I've been messing around with this one and it does not like sheet names with spaces in them. I tried using the sheet names with spaces like `'Sheet 7'`, and while that passes the `IsError(...)` check, I get a `'9' Subscript out of range` error. I thought using `With Worksheets("wsarray(i)")` would help, but that causes it to not work with everything, spaces or no spaces. Thoughts?

Comment: Change `wsarray(i) & "!A1"` to `"'" & wsarray(i) & "'!A1"`

Comment: I thought that `Worksheets(...)` needed quotes around anything that had spaces. Why would that not be the case when using it with an array? Is there something underlying that handles the spaces or adds the quotes during execution?

Comment: No it just needs to be a string.  You only need to change the part in the evaluate.

Comment: @Trevor I have edited the code to deal with spaces in the names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option, very similar to Scott's, but making use of a few more arrays to handle your ranges:

```
Sub retpsh()
    Dim Back As Worksheet: Set Back = Worksheets("Home Backstage")
    Dim wsarray As Variant
    Dim fromRangeArray As Variant
    Dim toRangeArray As Variant
    Dim message As String: message = Back.Cells(18, 13)
    Dim ws As Variant

    If Back.Cells(18, 19) = 0 Then
        If MsgBox("Nothing selected!", vbOKOnly) = vbOK Then Exit Sub
    Else
        If MsgBox(message + " Do you wish to continue?", vbYesNo) = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        wsarray = Split(Back.Cells(18, 19).Value, ",")
    End If

    'Could do this into a single multidimensional array if you are a sadist
    fromRangeArray = Array("B1:B4", "B6:B9", "B11", "B18:C22")
    toRangeArray = Array("C2:C5", "C8:C11", "C13", "B18:C22")

    'loop through sheet names
    For Each ws In wsarray
        For rngIndex = 0 To UBound(fromRangeArray)
            Sheets(ws).Range(toRangeArray(rngIndex)).Value = Back.Range(fromRangeArray(rngIndex)).Value
        Next rngIndex
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: I was just about to edit mine to drop the sheet loop.  I was going to add a check to ensure that the sheet actually exists.  but you beat me to it, so I will leave mine as is.

Comment: You should totally add a check to make sure the sheet exists in yours. I kept hitting `subscript out of range` and thought for sure it was an array/index issue. That would have saved me about 3 minutes of debugging.

Comment: I've never seen that `Application.Evaluate(wsarray(i) & "!A1")` before. I would have had to to set an error handler and handle it like that.. which just causes a spaghetti dinner. totally going to remember this one.

Comment: I also changed the `For Each` to a `For`.  Mat'sMug showed me an article that showed looping through an array is quicker with a `For`.  `For Each` is quicker with collections. Just an FYI.  I doubt in this instance of 4 max it would make any difference.

Comment: That's crazy about the `For Each` vs `For`. I guess it's not unreasonable though since an Array is such a lightweight object (compared to collections and dictionaries) so it's probably lighter weight to just hit a specific index on the fly then it is to set a variable in each iteration. Does that hold up if you set the element inside the `for` loop to a variable, or is it only if you hit the element by index once per loop?

Comment: That is a good question, I am not sure. Next time i get in a debate with the master I will ask.